# How do you connect localhost in the Android emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, localhost, httpconnection, androidhttpclient

I have made a php script inside *localhost* and I am connecting that with `httpClient` but I am getting a problem.

Please tell me how can I connect to a php file at *localhost* from the emulator?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Thanks, @lampShaded for your answer.

In your API/URL directly use `http://10.0.2.2:[your port]/` and under emulator setting add the proxy address as 10.0.2.2 with the port number. For more, you can visit: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html

[image]

Comment: This one is working for me. Great.

Answer (score 939):

#### Use `10.0.2.2` to access your actual machine.

As you've learned, when you use the emulator, `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) refers to the device's own loopback service, not the one on your machine as you may expect.

You can use 10.0.2.2 to access your actual machine, it is an alias set up to help in development.

Comment: Nice though this isn't useful for e.g. oauth though where a clientID is only valid for `localhost`

Comment: 10.0.2.2 not working for me in case of https localhost, do i have to use different ip in case of https?

Comment: But you need to change API from "localhost:port" to "127.0.0.1:port" first. after that, Use 10.0.2.2 to access your actual machine.

Comment: Is there any possibility to use siteurl/siteHost instead of ip, i can not use ip?

Comment: This is probably the best solution and it doesn't require proxy configuration on AVD (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217370/6422750 actually doesn't either). You can access your endpoints defined on the server via `http://10.0.2.2:<port_your_server_runs_on>/<path>`.

Comment: what in case when one wants to access the localhost along with the subdomain?

Comment: 10.0.2.2 works for me.

Answer (score 98):

Use `10.0.2.2` for default AVD and `10.0.3.2` for Genymotion

Comment: Is this answer relevant anymore?

Comment: Yes, still working by the end of 2023. Also don't forget to add port after the `10.0.2.2`

Comment: I forgot to add the port and pulling out of my hair saying why it's not working 

Answer (score 35):

This is what finally worked for me.

- Backend running on localhost:8080
- Fetch your IP address (ipconfig on Windows)

[image]

- Configure your Android emulator's proxy to use your IP address as host name and the port your backend is running on as port (in my case: 192.168.1.86:8080
  [image]
- Have your Android app send requests to the same URL (192.168.1.86:8080) (sending requests to localhost, and http://10.0.2.2 did not work for me)

Comment: This works for me too but I believe proxy is not necessary - logs on my Flask server showed that when proxy was configured, AVD generated plenty of weird and unnecessary GETs and CONNECTs that resulted in 404s. Switching back to `Use Android Studio HTTP proxy settings` fixed it and now the server receives only valid requests that I explicitly want. One more thing you could do for your convenience is assign a static IP address to your machine, for instance via your router settings so that DHCP won't be able to change it.

Answer (score 23):

Thanks to author of this blog: https://bigdata-etl.com/solved-how-to-connect-from-android-emulator-to-application-on-localhost/

Defining network security config in xml

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
       <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

And setting it on `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
</application>
```

Solved issue for me!

Please refer: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

Comment: What is the filename for the security config xml? The blog link is no longer up. Edit: it's in res/xml/network_security_config.xml

Comment: Heled me just replace the ip address with your ip or domain name

Answer (score 14):

you should change the adb port with this command:

```
adb reverse tcp:8880 tcp:8880; adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081; adb reverse tcp:8881 tcp:8881
```

Comment: my local server has a custom url. How do I port forward or reverse it?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of giving localhost give the IP.

Comment: What IP? I have no public IP as I work in local server, did you mean loopback ip `127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: Fetch your IP address (ipconfig on Windows), here IP means IPv4 like 192.168.100.4

Comment: what IP do you mean? please be specific