# Glassfish Android

Tags: android, wsdl, glassfish

I'm trying to connect android to glassfish and i have a question, if my glassfish server is on my localhost then what should i put as:

SoapAction, MethodName, Namespace, and URL?? I have tried this but didn't work: (in order)

http://localhost:8080/Echo
echo
http://localhost:8080
http://localhost:8080/webservice/EchoService?wsdl

can anyone please point me to where i should look, or the proper way to do this?

Note: Echo is a java class that have the echo method it just recieve a String and returns it...  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android understands local host it self so you have to use IP Address instead of localhost.

for more details refer this

[Connect-Localhost-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-to-connect-localhost-in-androd-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

When your application is deployed on Glassfish you can get the webservice URL in the admin console at 
http://localhost:4848

You should be able to check your web services to the left in the menu when you are logged in, there you can find the wsdl url for your service.