# Java TcpConnection

Tags: java, android, tcp

Hello I have a code written in Java and I need to create an TCP Connection with GPS device in android studio, where you can type in IP/PORT addresses, if someone can help me thanks in advance.

```
public class TCPConnection implements Runnable {

/**
 * <h1>TCP Connection construct</h1>
 * <p>The tcp connection requires two parameters socket and view model. </p>
 * @param socket to establish connection.
 * */





TCPConnection(Socket socket) {
    super();
    this.socket = socket;
    converter = new Converter();
    crc16 = new Crc16();
}






/**
 * <h1>Run function to start listener</h1>
 * <p>Simply runs the runnable thread to listen everything from client</p>
 * */

public void run() {
    try {
        inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        Listen();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Probably I need to create an button to start Listen incoming connections, also use Log class .....

```
 /**
 * <h1>Listen</h1>
 * <p>Function for listening connected client</p>
 * @throws IOException throws exception if input stream is interrupted
 * */
private void Listen() throws IOException {
    while (flag) {
        System.out.println("listening...");
        while (!socket.isClosed() && inputStream.available() == 0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                break;
            }
        }
        Communicate();
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
    socket.close();
}











/**
 * <h1>Get Number Of Records</h1>
 * <p>Reads the number of records to send back to the sender</p>
 * @param data the parameter is a received hex data
 * @return String format number of records
 * */
private String GetNumberOfRecords(String data) {
    return data.substring(18, 20);
}
```

Everything is written in a comments line, why stackoverflow says add more details :D...

```
/**
 * <h1>Communicate</h1>
 * <p>A reader and sender with client, first it reads imei, then sends back 01.
 * It receives data, as soon it receives it sends back number of records.
 * The while loop initializes and runs until it get interrupted or client disconnects.</p>
 * */
private void Communicate()  {

    imei =  Objects.requireNonNull(ReadInput()).substring(4);
    imei = converter.ReadImei(imei);
    String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop";
    logger = new Logger(path+"/Logs/TCPLogs/"+imei);
    logger.PrintToLOG(GetTime()+" IMEI: " +imei);
    if(imei.length() < 15){
        SendOutput("00");
    }
    else{
        SendOutput("01");
        logger.PrintToLOG("\tResponse: [0" + 1 + "]");
        String input = ReadInput();
        Log(Objects.requireNonNull(input));
        while(flag){
            String recordsCount = GetNumberOfRecords(input);
            SendOutput("000000" + recordsCount);
            logger.PrintToLOG("\tCrc: " + Integer.toHexString(CRC(input)));
            logger.PrintToLOG("\tResponse: [000000" + recordsCount + "]\n");
            input = ReadInput();
            Log(Objects.requireNonNull(input));
        }
    }


/**
 * <h1>Send Output</h1>
 * <p>Sends output to the client</p>
 * @param message the parameter is a received hex data
 * */
private void SendOutput(String message)  {
    try {
        outputStream.write(converter.StringToByteArray(message));
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Output stream was interrupted");
    }
}








/**
 * <h1>CRC</h1>
 * <p>Calculates CRC of received data</p>
 * @param str the parameter is a received hex data
 * @return int of crc16
 * */
private int CRC(String str) {
    str = str.substring(16, str.length() - 8);
    byte[] bytes = converter.StringToByteArray(str);
    return crc16.getCRC(bytes);
}












/**
 * <h1>Read Input</h1>
 * <p>Reads the input from client. Currently maximum message byte is set up to 8192,
 * if message is bigger then message will not be properly readable and displayed.</p>
 * @return String of received data
 * */
private String ReadInput() {
    byte[] messageByte = new byte[8192];
    int dataSize;
    try {
        dataSize = inputStream.read(messageByte);
        String finalInput = converter.BytesArrayToHex(messageByte, dataSize);
        SendToConsole(finalInput);
        return finalInput;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}














/**
 * <h1>Send To Console</h1>
 * <p>Simply prints out the results to the text area for user</p>
 * @param input the parameter is String format to print in text area
 * */
private void SendToConsole(String input) {
    if(imei!=null)
    {
        String message = viewModel.getClientMessage() + "\r\nFrom imei - "+imei+" : " + input + "\n" + repeatChar();
        Platform.runLater(() -> viewModel.setClientMessage(message));
    }
    else {
        String message = viewModel.getClientMessage() + "\r\nReceived imei - : " + input + "\n" + repeatChar();
        Platform.runLater(() -> viewModel.setClientMessage(message));
    }
}        









/**
 * <h1>Log</h1>
 * <p>Given String is being written to log file.</p>
 * @param data the parameter is a received data
 * */
private void Log(String data) {
    logger.PrintToLOG("\tcodec             : " + data.substring(16, 18));
    logger.PrintToLOG("\tNumber of Records : " + GetNumberOfRecords(data));
    logger.PrintToLOG("\tAVL data          : " + data + "\n");
}

/**
 * <h1>Set Running</h1>
 * <p>Sets flag to run or stop while loop in order to interrupt the thread.</p>
 * */
void setRunning() {
    this.flag = false;
}

/**
 * <h1>Repeat Char</h1>
 * <p>Repeats the '=' character multiple times.</p>
 * @return String is being returned.
 * */
private String repeatChar() {
    char[] data = new char[50];
    Arrays.fill(data, '=');
    return new String(data);
}

/**
 * <h1>Get Time</h1>
 * <p>Gets time when method is being called</p>
 * @return Time in String format
 * */
private String GetTime()
{
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalTime localTime = localDateTime.toLocalTime();
    return localTime.toString();
}


}

public class TCPServer implements Runnable {
private int port;
private Socket socket;
private ServerSocket ss;
private boolean running = true;
private ArrayList<TCPConnection> tcpConnections;

/**
 * <h1>TCP server construct</h1>
 * <p>The tcp server takes port parameter </p>
 * @param port is required for server to listen all incoming connections
 * */
public TCPServer(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}

/**
 * <h1>Run</h1>
 * <p>Runs the runnable thread to listen connections, it accepts a connection, if accept was successful,
 * the connection is added to tcpConnections list and runs the TCPConnection for further listening.
 * The server is running in while loop and stops when Running is set to false,
 * then break is called and shutdowns every connected client.</p>
 * */




public void run() {
    tcpConnections = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Listening on port : " + ss.getLocalPort());
        ExecutorService executorService;
        while (true) {
            executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            socket = ss.accept();
            TCPConnection connection = new TCPConnection(socket);
            executorService.submit(connection);
            tcpConnections.add(connection);
            if (!running) {
                StopConnections();
                break;
            }
        }
        executorService.shutdownNow();
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("socket is closed");
    }
}

/**
 * <h1>Set Flag</h1>
 * <p>Function is being called when we want to interrupt server thread and stop it.</p>
 * @param flag the parameter sets whenever to true(run server) or false(stop server)
 * */
public void setFlag(boolean flag) {
    running = flag;
    if (!running) {
        try {
            ss.close();
            if (socket != null)
                socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Socket is " + socket.isClosed());
        }
    }
}

/**
 * <h1>Stop Connections</h1>
 * <p>Function is being called when we are stopping server,
 * this function iterates through every connection and stops it.</p>
 * */
private void StopConnections() {
    if (!tcpConnections.isEmpty()) {
        for (TCPConnection connections : tcpConnections) {
            connections.setRunning();
        }
        tcpConnections.clear();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162775/really-simple-tcp-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android supports Java code as long as your android API level supports the Java version you are using. There shouldn't be any reason why you cannot use this in Android.

Just note that Android will throw an exception if you run any network tasks on the UI thread. E.g. Creating a socket should be run as an IntentService or AsyncTask, there are other options as well.