# Kotlin BufferReader is not getting Server response

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bufferedreader

I'm really new in Kotlin.
I have two application one is Client in Android emulator and one is in Windows Form Application Server (My server is Using `SimpleTCP` library in C#) .

Here is the Server Code:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        server = new SimpleTcpServer();
        server.Delimiter = 0x13;
        server.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
        server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived;
        
        messageList.Text += "Server starting...";
        server.Start("192.168.1.7", 5000);
        messageList.Text += "\r\n Server started...";
    }
    private void Server_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
    {
                messageList.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                {
                     messageList.Text += string.Format("\r\n Client Message: {0} \n ", e.MessageString);
                });
                e.ReplyLine("Hello from Server");
    }
```

I'm communicating via localhost. I can send request and Server can get this request without problem but when i try to get response from Server unfortunately cannot receive response.
`val message = input!!.readLine()` is always returning null

Can you help me why i cannot do this?

Here my code

```
var thread: Thread? = null
var etIP: EditText? = null
var etPort: EditText? = null
var tvMessages: TextView? = null
var etMessage: EditText? = null
var btnSend: Button? = null
var SERVER_IP: String? = null
var SERVER_PORT = 0
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    etIP = findViewById(R.id.etIP)
    etPort = findViewById(R.id.etPort)
    tvMessages = findViewById(R.id.tvMessages)
    etMessage = findViewById(R.id.etMessage)
    btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btnSend)
    val btnConnect: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnConnect)
    btnConnect.setOnClickListener {
        tvMessages!!.text = ""
        SERVER_IP = etIP!!.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
        SERVER_PORT = etPort!!.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }.toInt()
        thread = Thread(Thread1())
        thread!!.start()
    }
    btnSend!!.setOnClickListener {
        val message = "Android!"+etMessage!!.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
        if (!message.isEmpty()) {
            Thread(Thread3(message)).start()
        }
    }
}

private var output: PrintWriter? = null
private var input: BufferedReader? = null

internal inner class Thread1 : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        val socket: Socket
        try {
            socket = Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT)
            output = PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream())
            input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))
            runOnUiThread(Runnable { tvMessages!!.text = "Connected\n" })
            Thread(Thread2()).start()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

internal inner class Thread2 : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                val message = input!!.readLine().toString()
                run {
                    runOnUiThread(Runnable { tvMessages!!.append("server: $message\n") })
                }
                run {
                    thread = Thread(Thread1())
                    thread!!.start()
                    return
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                tvMessages!!.text = e.toString()
            }
        }
    }
}

internal inner class Thread3(private val message: String) : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        output!!.write(message)
        output!!.flush()
        runOnUiThread(Runnable {
            tvMessages!!.append("client: $message\n")
            tvMessages!!.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod())
            etMessage!!.setText("")
        })
    }
}
fun clearAll(view: View){
   tvMessages!!.text = ""
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot get request"? Do you get any exceptions or does it just block indefinitely? What does the server look like? The `BufferedReader` might be waiting for a new line character that the server isn't sending.

Comment: @JoachimSauer when i send server mesaage like “hi Server” i’m response from Server “hi Client” but Client cannot receive it

Comment: I guess you read wrong because in my question there is no ”cannot get request”...

Comment: Sure, that was a typo on my part, but the question still stands: **what happens** instead of you receiving the response? Do you get an exception or does everything just stop? Can you describe the problematic behaviour. *Something* is happening, what is that. Also: what does the server look like? That's kind of important to understand if the client is written correctly.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Ok You are right i will edit my question

Comment: @JoachimSauer so do you have any suggession about solution or  is it still not clear to you?

Comment: I don't know what SimpleTCP is so I don't know how it behaves, sorry. You might need someone who understands that (and adopt the tags accordingly).

Comment: @JoachimSauer i solved it my self thanks