# How to communicate between Android app and Webots robot

Tags: java, python, android, android-studio, webots

I have an Android app simulated on Android Studio and written in Java and a robot simulated in Webots using python. I am trying to figure out a way for them to communicate between each other so for example, the app can send a signal to webots to start/stop the robot, or the robot can send error messages to the app.

The only way I can think of doing this is to have them communicate through a web server, although I'm not sure how this will work in practice? Is there any other ways to do this or some libraries or specific methods I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement client server communication using [TCP/IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162775/really-simple-tcp-client) or UDP sockets.
Webot does supports implementing TCP/IP socket. You can find more info [here](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/interfacing-webots-to-third-party-software-with-tcp-ip).