# Couchbase Sync Gateway doesn't sync between Couchbase Lite and Couchbase Server

Tags: ionic-framework, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

i have a very big problem. I'm building an app at the moment. When I start the App with the Android emulator it works fine. I can save some Data and it will show me these too. So it saves the Data locally. (Couchbase Lite)
I work with an ionic framework. 
Now I want to sync between Couchbase Server and Couchbase Lite.
I use the Sync Gateway, but it doesn't work.
Below you can see my sync-gateway-config.json and my log.
Can someone help me please?

```
{
   "interface": ":4984",
   "adminInterface": "0.0.0.0:4985",
   "log": ["*"],
   "databases":  {
      "syncdb":    {
         "server": "http://127.0.0.1:8091",
         "bucket": "sync_gateway",
         "username": "sync_gateway",
         "password": "********",
         "sync":
             function (doc)  {
                 channel (doc.channels);
             },
          "users": {
            "GUEST": {
                "disabled": true,
                "admin_channels": ["public"]
            },
            "Administrator": {
                "disabled": false,
                "password": "**********",
                "admin_channels": ["*"]
            }
       }
    }
```

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxBF7.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Android emulator uses a special address to connect to the machine it runs on.  Set your app to connect to Sync Gateway via 10.0.2.2.  See [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-to-connect-localhost-in-android-emulator) for more information.

Comment: I already set my app to connect to Sync Gateway via 10.0.2.2, but it shows the same log and doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can add the property: "import_docs": "continuous", and "enable_shared_bucket_access": true, in your database config, between syncdb braces, to see if there is a differencee.
`"syncdb":    {
         "import_docs": "continuous",
         "enable_shared_bucket_access": true,
         "server": "http://127.0.0.1:8091",
         ........
               }`