# android no data when fetching from mysql php and no error

Tags: php, android, mysql

I created an android app that fetch data from mysql database using localhost wamp server, but the problem is there is no data when I run the app and there is no any error in log,

and when I run my php file (test.php) using the browser it shows data

http://127.0.0.1:81/Test/test.php

here is the code where I added the php url:

```
  private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "http://127.0.0.1:81/MyApi/Api.php";
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: if you run application in to your device then i should be having connected to your Local PC or with that WIFI

Comment: Have you tried this? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-to-connect-localhost-in-android-emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-to-connect-localhost-in-android-emulator)

Comment: @ND1010 I didn't tested it on my phone, I used emulator.

Comment: ok compare your URL for both @ PHP side and @ android side

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using this IP: 10.0.2.2

thanks to szamani20 and this post:

[how to connect localhost in android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-to-connect-localhost-in-android-emulator)