# Ionic4 http request not working on Android Device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

So far REST API get method working in my local ng serve , but in my device not working.

Android device remote debug showing :URL:'localhost/get/list'

**proxy.config.json**

```
"/code":{   
        "target": "http://192.x.x.x:8010",   
        "secure":false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    },
```

**Serive Get Method:**

```
      this.service.getUrl('/get/list','level=2').subscribe(
        data=>{ //Android Device URL :localhost/get/list not showing proxy.config.url

});
```

**package.json**

```
"start": "ng serve   --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

**Remote Debug Result:**I can't get **_body** result like local result , it's seems getting index.html page.

[image: Android Remote DEBUG]

**Local ng Serve Result:**
[image: Local]

Comment: Are you running in an emulator or on your actual phone?

Comment: Actual Phone as well as Emulator

Comment: How are you hosting your API? Who is serving it? Is it configured to allow outside connections? Does 10.0.2.2 work on the emulator?

Comment: IP:10.0.2.2 not connected success , need to config from outside IP (192.X.X.X.X:8080)

Comment: Is 8080 open to the outside? And whatever server you are using configured to allow outside connections?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the emulator and the API is on your local machine, change the IP address in `proxy.config.json` to `10.0.2.2`. Check out [How do you connect localhost in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator)