# My app in running in android studio emulator is not loading localhost database contents

Tags: android, android-studio, localhost, wamp

I have build an app and installed in my android studio emulator. One of the activity contains a recycler view which loads contents from database. The database was in localhost and I fetch the contents using php code. I have used "http://192.168.1.101/fetch.php" to fetch the contents. But the app is not able to load the contents while running in emulator on the other hand when I run it in my android phone it runs smoothly.

I am using WAMP. I can access internet in emulator (checked some websites using chrome etc). But problem occurs in case of this database content retrival.

I am a beginner in app development. So it will be very helpful if you provide the answers in an easily understandable way.

Please help me how to solve these problem..

Comment: There is not enough information here to determine what is happening. What error do you get and where? Is `http://192.168.1.101/fetch.php` accessible through built in browser? BTW if `192.168.1.101` is localhost then you should use `10.0.2.2` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator

Comment: I have already tried 10.0.2.2  but showing no adapter attached skipping layout.. while loading in emulator

Comment: In such case you have to then share the actual code snippet, as small as possible and exception you get.

Comment: No other exception showing.. Only " no adapter attached.. skipping layout "