# android application with localhost

Tags: c#, sql, xamarin

I have a Xamarin.Android application and I want the android emulator to get access to my database on localhost, I want to connect my application to my database by IP address. Here is the code I have so far:

```cs
var gridview1 = FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gvd);
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1);

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost:1433;Initial Catalog = DB_B2B; Integrated Security = True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from en_cours");
con.Open();
cmd.Connection = con;
SqlDataReader sqlreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (sqlreader.Read())
{
    adapter.Add((string)sqlreader[0]);
}
sqlreader.Close();
con.Close();
```

This is the error I receive when trying to connect:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>
> Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN9, error: 44 - SNI_ERROR_44)
>
> Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN9, error: 44 - SNI_ERROR_44)

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What is your question ?

Comment: well localhost is always 127.0,0.1 ... IP of what exactly?

Comment: i'm trying to connect my android emulateur application with my localhost database , i'm trying this '             SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 192.168.1.100,1433; Initial Catalog = DB_B2B; Integrated Security = True");   but it's not working

Comment: Is the database on the Android or the machine that Android is connected to?  Is the database mounted on the SQL Server?  You never answer fully my questions from earlier posting.  If I got the full answers I would be able to help much better.

Comment: @jdweng i'm sorry , the database is in the machine , yes the database mounted on the SQL server ,

Comment: Could you post the code you have, which is not working ? Could you also post the specific error you have ? (not the full logcat, only the error)

Comment: @ArthurAttout i'm editing my question

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya what do you mean ?

Comment: Do you have localhost URL with you like htps://localhost

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya i don't think soo

Comment: As I said in previous posting you have a credential issue.  Three things must occur 1) The Android and the Server Machine needs to be in the same Group 2) A User Group Account needs to be setup on Android and Server Machine  3) Each user needs to be placed in the Group.

Comment: @jdweng and how can i do that ??

Comment: It is done as Admin with windows settings and User Group.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android emulators, if you want to connect to the hosting machine you should use 10.0.2.2 and not localhost.

If you use 127.0.0.1 or localhost, the App will try to access the local network on the emulator itself, which is not the same network as the host machine.

This is also answered in this StackOverflow QA: [How do you connect localhost in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator)