# Flutter socket io doesn't connect to node js socket io server

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io

I'm trying to build a simple flutter chat application using a node.js matchmaking server. I've worked with this for a few hours already but I simple cannot get the app to connect with the server.

Here's the node js server:

```
var express=require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var allClients = {};

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    io.to(socket.id).emit('userCount', Object.keys(allClients).length);
    console.log(socket.id,'joined');
    //match making logic
});

var port = 8080;
console.log(port);
server.listen(port);
```

Flutter connecting code:

```
//Find a match for the user
void findMatch() async {
    SocketIO socketIO = SocketIOManager().createSocketIO("http://192.168.0.32:8080", "/");
    print('Created');
    await socketIO.init(); //code execution pauses indefinitely at this line
    print('Initialized');
    await socketIO.connect();
    print('Connected');

    socketIO.sendMessage('new user', data);

    socketIO.subscribe('match found', (data) async {
      UserData peerData = await getUserData(data.peerId);
      redirectToPage(context, Chat(peerId: data.peerId, peerData: peerData));
    });
}
```

When the function is run, the code execution pauses at the line shown above, and the node js server doesn't react at all. However this shows up on the debug console.

```
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: FlutterSocketIoPlugin( 4490): onMethodCall: socketInit - domain: http://192.168.0.32:8080 - with namespace: /
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: TOTAL SOCKETS: ( 4490): 0                                                                 
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: TOTAL SOCKETS: ( 4490): 0                                                                 
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: added SocketIO( 4490): http://192.168.0.32:8080/                                          
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO( 4490): connecting...null
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

I wrote a simple node js client as suggested in the comments, and it connects to the server successfully.

```
//client.js
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080', {reconnect: true});

// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connect', function (socket) {
    console.log('Connected!');
});
socket.emit('CH01', 'me', 'test msg');
```

Edit:

Removing the 'await's before the socket functions in findMatch() gets me this.

```
D/FlutterSocketIoPlugin: SocketIO(21368): reconnect_error: [{"cause":{"cause":{"detailMessage":"CLEARTEXT communication to 192.168.0.32 not permitted by network security policy","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]},"detailMessage":"websocket error","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]},"detailMessage":"Connection error","stackTrace":[],"suppressedExceptions":[]}]
```

I tried `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` but it doesn't seem to work.  Changing http to https gives `SSL handshake aborted`. Maybe deploying the socket server on a remote machine with an SSL certificate will work? Will continue digging.

Comment: Can you try to wrap this line with a `try...catch`?

Comment: Are you referring to the line where execution pauses?

Comment: Yes. It is possible that there is an un-catched error

Comment: @AugustinR Nope, no error was revealed

Comment: Silly question. You've tested your API with a different client and it's working as intended?

Comment: I haven't done that.. But the code above is all I've written. I'll try to get something up asap.

Comment: @JoãoSoares I wrote a simple socket io client using node js and it connects to the server.

Comment: But your node client, works when in another machine? Maybe Firewall is blocking the attempt or something that... try in another device with your "node client" using LAN connection attempt

Comment: I guess you are testing in emulator running on the system with ip 192.168.0.32 (localhost), if that so you will have to use 10.0. 2.2 IP in your emulator. More info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator

Comment: @RenêGuilhermeNucci Tried it and the connection is working. :/

Comment: @HiteshGupta Nope, am testing on my android phone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried above code with this flutter plugin [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_socket_io) as I think you are also using the same, but I also got the same problem. I tried to see any error log generated by `Logcat` and I found an entry `connecting...null` and it was stuck there but don't know how to fix or what is the problem. I tried it with another flutter plugin [here](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client) and tested it in emulator, it worked fine for below sample code. If you can use a different flutter plugin then this might be useful.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.id, 'joined');
    socket.on('/test', function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
});

var port = 8080;
console.log(port);
server.listen(port);
```

Flutter client code -

```
IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://10.0.2.2:8080', <String, dynamic>{
   'transports': ['websocket'],
   'autoConnect': false,
});
socket.connect();
socket.emit('/test', 'test');
```

Comment: Thanks @Hitesh Gupta. I spent 2 days to check all the possible issues. but now when I changed the plugin, it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 13):

`Downgrading` my server's `socket.io version` worked for me. Just as above, if you are using `nodejs` try uninstalling socket.io and installing an older version as follows:

```sh
npm uninstall socket.io
npm install socket.io@2.3.0
```

Most flutter socket io client packages are compatible with `socket.io` `version 2.3.0`. I would recommend you downgrade to this incase you are experiencing a similar problem.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me!

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading your server's socket io version. Some socket io client packages(flutter) are not compatible with the latest server-side socket io (node.js). My server configuration was using version 3.0.4. For some reason, it was incompatible with  `adhara_socket_io: 0.4.2` and `socket_io_client: 0.9.12`. By downgrading my node.js socket io version worked for both client libraries

```
npm uninstall socket.io
npm install socket.io@2.3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

work too

## server(nodejs)  => "socket.io": "^2.4.1"

## client(flutter) =>  socket_io_client: ^1.0.1

Comment: what about server(nodejs) "socket.io": "2.4.0" ?