# Connect from Android to RabbitMQ

Tags: android, rabbitmq

I'm trying to consume a rabbitMq queue and append the message to a `TextView` but I get this  error:

```
java.net.ConnectException:failed to connect to to /127.0.0.1(port 5672) from/127.0.0.1(port 49582)after 6000ms:isConnected failed:ECONNREFUSED(Connection refused)
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String QUEUE_NAME = "Invitation2";
    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.ident);
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
                factory.setHost("localhost");
                Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
                Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
                channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
                DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
                    String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
                    try {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                tv.append(message);
                            }
                        });
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.i("error", e.toString());
                    }
                };
                channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { });
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.i("error", e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide your source code instead of an image, so we can help you.

Comment: ok now I've changed it

Comment: Is the RabbitMQ service up and running?

Comment: yes it's running

Comment: Is the port correct?

Comment: yes, and I even set the port to 5672 but it didn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5528850/208273: Use 10.0.2.2 instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you connect localhost in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator)

Comment: Thank you @RyanM, actually this was my end of studies project last year, RabbitMQ didn't work well in my project and I ran out of time so I had to do something else without RabbitMQ.

Comment: Mobile clients typically are not directly connected to backend services such as message queues, anyway