# I cannot connect to localhost WebAPI with Android Emulator in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.android

So I am currently building a Xamarin.forms app that will pull data from a WebAPI project I have hosted on localhost:62568. The API itself is working as it should when I use a tool like postman, but while attempting to connect to it with the Android Emulator, I'm met with an Http 400 error. I am aware that Android uses its own loopback at 10.0.2.2:port.

After reading up on several different posts, I have attempted to change the proxy settings of the Android emulator to use 10.0.2.2 as well as my local IP with no luck.
[Android emulator running with 10.0.2.2 as the proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgt5p.png)

There seems to be a lot of different [fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator) out there that I haven't had any luck with. Is there anything recent for this issue?

I'm relatively new to all this so let me know if something isn't clear. Thank you!

Comment: Please rephrase your question as a question to fit the Stack Overflow format.  Good luck on your issue.

Comment: You must learn the actual networking details behind the scene https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-let-android-emulator-access-iis-express-f6530a02b1d3 so as to know if someone's advice works or not and why. Honestly speaking, most posts/discussions never go deep into the details, so they can easily be confusing.

Comment: I saw this link a few times and thought it shouldn't be necessary to use external software for this. But this ended up working for me. At least in the android web browser. Thanks a bunch!