# How do i connect to http in nativescript from Android ver 9.0?

Tags: angular, nativescript

> Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
>
> LOG from device OnePlus 3T: "headers": {}
>   LOG from device OnePlus 3T: },
>   LOG from device OnePlus 3T: "status": 0,
>   LOG from device OnePlus 3T: "headers": {
>   LOG from device OnePlus 3T: {
>   LOG from device OnePlus 3T: "lazyUpdate": null,
>   LOG from device OnePlus 3T: "statusText": "Unknown Error",
>   LOG from device OnePlus 3T: "url": "http://myurl",
>   LOG from device OnePlus 3T: "ok": false,
>   LOG from device OnePlus 3T: "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
>   LOG from device OnePlus 3T: "message": "Http failure response for http://myurl: 0 Unknown Error",
>   LOG from device OnePlus 3T: "error": {
>   LOG from device OnePlus 3T: "originalStack": "Error: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to myIP not permitted
>
> at new ZoneAwareError (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:1298:33)
>   at onRequestComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/http/http-request/http-request.js:54:34)
>   at Object.onComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/@nativescript/core/http/http-request/http-request.js:43:13)",
>
> LOG from device OnePlus 3T: "zoneAwareStack": "Error: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to myIP not perm...
>   LOG from device OnePlus 3T: "normalizedNames": {},

Comment: Please do provide more insight into the state of your problem. How did this problem occur? what were you trying to achieve? so that other community members can give you alternative solutions

Comment: this problem occur when i try to login my app, this  works in android v.7 , but it show this error while trying with android v 9

Comment: i have added the network_security_config_xml file and i have also added this code android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in my android manifest file but still i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I tried different approaches that didn't work. I finally resolved to tunnel my localhost to the internet using [localtunnel](https://localtunnel.github.io/www/) and used the link provided as my base url in my http calls.

I also found a number of useful [Stack overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator) that resolved similar issues using other approaches.