# How to send a simple String msg in Android Studio in Kotlin to a api within network or some other test location

Tags: android, api, kotlin

I've tried various approaches and never succeeded, even tried spring (not sure if it's good for FE), I simply want to send a string form an android client (from a textfield by send would be even better) to an api (local in the network) so that I can start specifying the api etc... I started a Springboot tomcat Server with intellij an ran this or more or less similar code on android studio and nothing ever arrived on my localhost:
'''

```
package com.example.test

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import org.w3c.dom.Text


const val EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.tbv.MESSAGE"
var text: String = ""

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun sendApi() {
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "http://192.168.178.70:8080/testApi" //also tested 10.0.2.2
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url,
            { response ->
        text = "Response is: ${response.substring(0, 500)}"
    },

    { text = "That didn't work!" })
  
    queue.add(stringRequest)

    Toast.makeText(this, "respooooonse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    startActivity(intent)
    }
    }
```

'''

as said, I've tried a variety of approaches, so I'm looking more for a general error in my approach.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBnLF.jpg)

so the api should be sent as the response toast is showing. the request should show in the localhost 8080? im sending it from androidstudio to my local ip (in this case 192.168.178.70)
Also tried sending to 10.0.2.2:8080, changing settings in the emulator and adding server.address=127.0.0.1 to application.properties in intellij

Comment: If you are using an emulator you are using the wrong adress to connect to.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator
The IP is : 10.0.2.2 for your pc, when you are using an emulator

Answer (score 0):

The solution should be to specify the Ip address of your computer instead of localhost (127.0.01) because in the context of the app localhost will be the android device on which the app runs.

Comment: thank you for the fast reply! I added a screenshot and some explanation to it, still not working :-/

Answer (score 0):

This is your Android device: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/testApi` ...therefore it makes no sense.
If you want to connect *another* host, you probably should change the IP address accordingly.