# Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake

Tags: flutter, api, rest, postman, http-post

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1cNh.png)I am new to flutter. I connected to a local API.I am getting Connection Terminated Error

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

class Registration extends StatefulWidget {
  const Registration({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Registration> createState() => _RegistrationState();
}
class _RegistrationState extends State<Registration> {
  TextEditingController _first_controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _last_controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _address_controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _email_controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _phone_controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _gender_controller = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _password_controller = TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
```

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.white,
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,

```
appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Registration',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                color: Colors.white)),
      ),
 body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: _formkey,
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 12),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                          controller: _first_controller,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
```

decoration: InputDecoration(
labelText: 'First Name',
labelStyle: TextStyle(
fontSize:
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 22),
border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
suffixIcon:
const Icon(Icons.person_add_alt_1_outlined),
),
validator: (value) {
if (value == null || value == "") {
return "Please Enter First Name ";
} else {
return null;
}
},
),
SizedBox(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 50,
),
TextFormField(
textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
controller: _last_controller,
keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
decoration: InputDecoration(
labelText: 'Last Name',
labelStyle: TextStyle(
fontSize:
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 22),
border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
suffixIcon:
const Icon(Icons.person_add_alt_1_outlined),
),
validator: (value) {
if (value == null || value == "") {
return "Please Enter Last Name ";
} else {
return null;
}
},
),
SizedBox(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 50,
),
TextFormField(
textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
controller: _address_controller,
keyboardType: TextInputType.streetAddress,
decoration: InputDecoration(
labelText: 'Address',
labelStyle: TextStyle(
fontSize:
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 22),
border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
suffixIcon:
const Icon(Icons.location_city_outlined),
),
validator: (value) {
if (value == null || value == "") {
return "Please Enter Address ";
} else {
return null;
}
},
),
SizedBox(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 50,
),
TextFormField(
textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
controller: _phone_controller,
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
decoration: InputDecoration(
labelText: 'Phone Number',
labelStyle: TextStyle(
fontSize:
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 22),
border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
suffixIcon:
const Icon(Icons.mobile_friendly_outlined),
),
validator: (value) {
if (value == null ||
value == "" ||
value.length < 8) {
return "Please Enter Valid Mobile Number  ";
} else {
return null;
}
},
),
SizedBox(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 50,
),
TextFormField(
textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
controller: _email_controller,
keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
decoration: InputDecoration(
labelText: 'E-mail',
labelStyle: TextStyle(
fontSize:
MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 22),
border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
),
validator: (value) {
if (value == null || value == "") {
return "Please Enter E-mail ";
} else {
return null;
}
},
),
SizedBox(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 50,
),

```
TextFormField(
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                          controller: _gender_controller,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Gender',
                            helperText: 'Choice M or F',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 22),
                            border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                            suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.male_outlined),
                          ),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value == "") {
                              return "Please Enter Gender";
                            } else {
                              return null;
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 50,
                        ),
TextFormField(
                          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                          controller: _password_controller,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'Password',
                            helperText: 'Minimum strength = 3',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 22),
                            border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                            suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.visibility),
                          ),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null ||
                                value == "" ||
                                value.length < 3) {
                              return "Please Enter Valid Password";
                            } else {
                              return null;
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 50,
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            RegisterData();
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            'Register',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 22,
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                letterSpacing:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 209),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
 Future RegisterData() async {
    var url = "https://192.168.2.109:8085/Users";

    Map data = {
      'firstName': _first_controller.text,
      'lastName': _last_controller.text,
      'address': _address_controller.text,
      'phonenumber': _phone_controller.text,
      'email': _email_controller.text,
      'gender': _gender_controller.text,
      'password': _password_controller.text,
    };
    print("JSON DATA: $data");
    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: data);

    var mssg_data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print("DATA: $mssg_data");
  }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You get a handshake exception whenever your app's http client reject a call before it goes to the respective Rest Service.
By default, the flutter's http client rejects calls that trying to communicate with an service having expired or unverified security certificate.

You can overwrite your default http client and make it to send requests to a rest service with invalid certificate by using this code example:

```
void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
```

Also, if the problem remains, we should investigate it a little bit more. If you use an emulator, maybe, the app cannot communite with your local server, if so, you can solve it by following this thread: [How do you connect localhost in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243628/discussion-on-answer-by-prodromos-sarakinou-unhandled-exception-handshakeexcept).

Answer (score 2):

I just had this error message randomly pop up.  Things were working fine before ... To resolve, it was a change/switch from a HTTPS API call to a  HTTP API call ... Fortunately the client offered a HTTP connection as well ... Hope this helps : )

Comment: Don't do this! The S in HTTPS is there for a reason. It stands for secure, meaning that the connection is encrypted. Switching to an unsecure connection does not solve the problem, it circumvents it. But you should not use HTTP (without the s) on anything that should ever go to production, ever.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting handshake exceptions whenever I switch the date manually on my device or emulator and forget to put it back. I don't know if that's the problem in your case but give it a try and check if your dates are correct. Also sometimes in emulator it needs to delete it and recreate it to run properly.

Comment: Here I am getting this connection error, on clicking Register Button. I have tried giving permission in the android manifest file. But no change in output Error. What can I do...I tried a sample fake API...I am getting output. But local API I am not getting