# How do I tell Flutter that it is a safe site?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-run

I have now registered https domain in Cloud Run. It works very well on localhost, but not on real domain.

If I click on the ssl icon on my website, it says Google LLC Certified.

But I keep getting errors on my site.

```
unnhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake
```

It works when I do,

```
http.get('https://google.com')...
```

but it doesn't work when I do it from my site.

```
http.get('httpsmysitecom')...
```

And if I don't do it in Flutter with the same address and just turn on Chrome and hit the url, the rest api works well. Now I'm going crazy. Because of this, I got a new ssl on comodo as well.

Comment: `httpsmysitecom` is not valid URL

Comment: @Justinas I put like that because of Stackoverflow They forced it when I wrote this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65730723/8541577

Comment: @AzharHusainRaeisi Yup I saw that post too and I added NSAppTransportSecurity and  NSExceptionDomains (mydomain.com without https)

Comment: I tried this one, simple http not https, it works await http.get(Uri.parse('http://www.kts-transportservice.de/en/'));

Comment: using http: ^0.13.5

Comment: @AzharHusainRaeisi Hi my http is ^0.13.3 and my server url starts with https:// and it is made with Cloud Run. I used Google domain. and it is not working

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that this is a country-specific problem according to these threads:

- [Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61073515/20239914)
- [Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65351574/20239914)

So I would recommend you to try with VPN on so You can be sure that this is the issue here.

If that does not help there is also an possibility of following:

Every time the http client in your app rejects a call before it hits the appropriate Rest Service, you get a handshake exception. The http client for flutter automatically rejects requests made to services that use expired or unverified security certificates.

You can also overwrite your default http client and make it to send requests to a rest service with invalid certificate by using this example in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71751021/20239914)

Comment: I can`t make app users to use VPN. and I tried HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides() also.

Comment: @Julidi But have you tried to use VPN ? so it can be confirmed if that's the issue then we can narrow down our search

Comment: I am not able to understand about VPN ,are you telling me to change my server's ip address using a vpn or are you asking my users to install a vpn and use my app?

Comment: @Julidi No I mean test your application using VPN turned on