# Is there a way to connect to the emulator from the host?

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator

Using Android Studio on macOS works fine, but I cannot find any way to access the network of the emulator.
It appears to use a hardcoded IP address 10.0.2.2 which is not user configurable which does not match the 192.168.x.x subnet in which my computer is.
I tried 'redir' which can be run from a clunky Telnet session which only works once and every time when openinh `telnet localhost 5554` one has to input a weird auth token, which is very user unfriendly.
And I found on several pages that there is a proxy page in the settings screen of the emulator. It should be like this page: [How do you connect localhost in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator)  But I could not find anything about a proxy in the settings screen.
Coping and pasting from/to the emulator is only possible through clunky adb calls and keystrokes using cmd / ctrl are ignored by the emulator. So any communication with the emulator is almost impossible.
Did I miss anything ?

Comment: Your goal is not clear. Connect to what? Take a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Answer (score 1):

Well I want to connect from host OS to the emulator.
After playing a bit, I found it myself, may be an idea for others who have similar questions.

EDIT: Using Termux on the emulator I made a reverse SSH tunnel starting:

`ssh -R 43022:localhost:8022 -R 6900:localhost:5900 macuser@10.0.2.2`

This makes an SSH connection to my Macbook. Then I started `sshd` from Termux to open ssh server (on port 8022) on Termux.

From macOS terminal I start `ssh -p 43022 user@localhost`

Then I have a connection into the emulator.

And I tried VNC (https://github.com/bk138/droidVNC-NG) using localhost:6900 which did work as well.

Using scrcpy (https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy, which I use to control my real smartphone from the computer) that works as well. No tunnels needed, works straight OOTB (out-of-the-box). In that case, copy/paste and ctrl keys work as they do when I control my real phone.
Genymotion should work under Windows as well. SSH tunneling is better suited for Applinux (macOS / Linux) users.

[Screenshot of droidVNC (showing Netguard)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeW8F.png)

Comment: This trick works to ssh from Winsows's Cygwin to Termux in the emulator. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm on win11 with openssh server enabled in "Turn windows features on or off"