# Maui problems accessing API

Tags: c#, maui

I have a API that runs without any problem. I tested with Postman and there is an MVC app running based on that API. Now I am developing a MAUI Android app that needs to access the same API but I can't make it work. I checked not only Microsoft but this site and others but no success. If I am not wrong I believe the problem is the Android Emulator. I am testing using the localhost for the API but I tried the 10.0.2.2 but no luck. I read that when using the Android Emulator it behaves like a different machine and when I run my Maui app it returns errors like:

> "Can't access the 127.0.0.1"

or something similar.

Any ideas how to solve this or any way around or some Emulator config?

This is the code I have to call the API: (the localhost has been replaced by 10.0.2.2 but no luck)

```cs
try
     {
            HttpClient client = new();
            Uri baseurl = new Uri("http://localhost:8082/api/Login/GetAllCustomers()");
         
            JsonSerializerOptions jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();

            //var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
            //{
            //{ "uname", uname },
            //{ "upsw", psw }
            //};
            //HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(baseurl);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //String contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               await Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
            }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            await this.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
    }
```

Also the commented part is for another function so once this is resolved I believe I will manage that works.

I tried to change the IPs based on the errors, but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55606008/4308455?

Comment: Have you tried using the actual IP of the server?

Comment: Make sure you have added network_security_config.xml as stated here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/local-web-services?view=net-maui-8.0#android-network-security-configuration

Comment: Hi Julian, thanks for your response. I followed the link using 10.0.2.2 and the IP from my machine but no luck, returning 400 - Bad request.

Comment: A 400 means that the request is reaching the server

Comment: Also, it’s very unusual to have a url that ends in “()”.  Are you sure that’s correct?

Comment: To all replies my big thanks. I managed to get through the IP issue but now I have to figure it out the 400 - Bad request I am having.. I am reviewing my API even tough it is working ok when I run on Postman or in the browser. I will try to get a better debug response to see what is happening. Again, thanks to you all...