# Unable to connect to API running on local host from android emulator

Tags: flutter, dart, asp.net-web-api, android-emulator, .net-8.0

I have been trying and failing to connect to a local instance of an API, that is running on localhost through IIS express on Visual Studio 2022. How do I make calls to the API while running a flutter application on android emulator? (developed on vs code)

I have tried updating the base url in the flutter project to 10.0.2.2:port and updating the proxy settings on the emulator as well. This has not worked. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Image of android emulator proxy settings]

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217370/13625293) (using 192.168.x.x)

Comment: @DhafinRayhan I have tried this, however I received an http 400 bad request - invalid hostname response

Answer (score 0):

Try to host your backend using IP Address 192.168.x.xxx instead of localhost / hostnames and try to hit it from your Flutter code inside the Emulator. It will can be simpler than registering the hostname (localhost).

Comment: I tried this, however I received an http 400 bad request - invalid hostname response

Comment: Now if you try 400, the main problem about "Unable to connect to API running on local host from android emulator" it's already solved then. It means there is something wrong inside your backend or request payload. And please make it resolved