# Can't connect to localhost in ADB, Android emulator

Tags: python, windows, adb, emulation

I'm using LDplayer4(as an Android emulator), and I was making a simple game macro in python
so I used pure-python-adb module to control it in python.

It worked before I moved the files to another PC but It's not working in new one.

Those are my questions :

- Is there any way to solve this problem below?
- If not, how to connect more than 20 emulators without using remote connect?

here is a part of my script where the error occurs.

```
client = [type(0)] * emulatorcnt
adbdevice = [type(0)] * emulatorcnt
    for i in range(emulatorcnt):
        client[i] = AdbClient(host="127.0.0.1", port=5037)
        client[i].remote_connect("localhost", ports[emulatorcnt]*2+5555))
        adbdevice[i] = client[i].device("localhost:" + str(ports[emulatorcnt]*2+5555))
```

- emulatorcnt is a integer which means the number of emulators I want to run at once
- ports[] is a integer which means the port number in LDplayer

For example,
[this instance works in port no. 5557](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIRqA.png)

*Since I am using pandas to store the port number, I have changed the example code to make it easier to understand. So you may see an error in the example, but it should not be a problem as it works fine on other PCs.*

The error occurs like this
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRi9Z.png)

I wanted to figure out the problem, so I changed the code like this

```
client = AdbClient(host="127.0.0.1", port=5037)
adbdevice = client.devices())
```

...And it worked fine, so remote_connect appears to be the problem.
But problem was not solved because I want to connect more than 20 emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the localhost (http://127.0.0.1) to http://10.0.2.2/ (For Android Emulator Loopback)

Source :

[How do you connect localhost in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator)
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html

[how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528850/how-do-you-connect-localhost-in-the-android-emulator)