How to run webview in Android Emulator pointing to localhost?
I'm trying to debug an issue within a webview in Android (the geolocation API doesn't work). It works on iOS and in the browser so I need to find out what's wrong with Android. To do this I want to run the app locally but instead of using the dev/staging webview url I want to point to my webapp running locally (localhost:8001). How do I do it? I'm a Web engineer, not an Android engineer so I'm probably missing something here.
I replaced the url from https://my-app.dev.com to http://localhost:8001 and ran the app in the Android emulator, but then the page opens in a regular browser and not inside the webview and it doesn't actually loads, but gives ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
What do I need to do to point the webview to my localhost? Asked ChatGPT and tried all the suggestions:

Using ngrok (it loads, but still opens in a regular browser not in the webview)
Replacing localhost with 10.0.2.2 (I get connection refused)

Thanks in advance!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55606008/5990846

@Jay No Proxy tab here, only Advanced tab.

You can just go to the Wi-Fi Settings on your emulator and find the proxy settings there.
